# How to do an insertion sort of a list of dictionaries by key without using sort BIF's?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I am learning Python at my University and I have an exercise that I can't figure out. I'm writing my own functions to understand how sorting a dictionary works without using the BIF for sorting. This is one part of a large exercise, and I just need to get off the ground. The dictionary is already in a list of dictionaries. This is what I have but it doesn't work, any help is appreciated.
oxford is a list of dictionaries (the dictionaries have lots of data inside)

```
def myInsertion(oxford, key) :
    temp = list() # creating new empty temporary list
    for key in oxford[:-1] : # looking thru all keys in list beginning at end
        temp.append(key) # adding key to temp list
    j = key
    while j < oxford[:-1] :  # comparing j the temp key with last position key
        temp[j] = oxford[j -1] # if true j replaces last position in oxford
        j = j - 1    # to stop continuous looping
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Are you getting an exception? (post a full traceback) Are you getting incorrect results? Don't just dump code and say it "doesn't work"

Comment: sorry... my program crashes, it gives me a 'Traceback' it says "TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < list()" . And thank you to Dan for making my code look like code. I hit 'enter' key after each line - I don't know how to made it look like code.

Comment: In this line: `for key in oxford[:-1] :` you aren't going backwards, you are omitting the last element. You want oxford[::-1]. Slice notation is start:stop:step. Also, why are you using the argument key in your myInsertion function? You don't use that anywhere and in fact shadow when you use your first for loop.

Comment: the key in the function is a variable passed from a previous function that holds a user's input. the user chooses what key to sort by.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are trying to do? It seems like you are trying to sort a list of dictionaries, not the dictionaries inside of the list, and also, I don't think you have grokked the slice notation yet.

Comment: I'm still not understanding your key variable. Are you trying to reproduce the behavior of the BIF `sorted`? If so, key in that BIF is actually suppose to be another function. Regardless, you are overwriting it when you use 'key' as the variable-name in your for-loop.

Comment: I am trying to sort the list oxford, which is a list of dictionaries. I'm trying to use an insertion sort without using any of the sorting built in functions of Python. I changed the slice operator to [::-1] in my program, but still got the "TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < list()" crash.

Comment: Because j is a dictionary and oxford[:-1] is a list of dictionaries. Indeed, in python 3 you can't compare dictionaries. So, if you have two dictionaries, e.g. A and B, and you try to do A < B you will get an error. Python 2 will try to compare dictionaries, I don't recall exactly how it worked. In any event, python 3 dropped this behavior because it isn't obvious how one should compare two dictionaries. Are you sure you are talking about dictionaries? Here's a shot in the dark, change your while statement to the following: `while j < oxford[-1]:`

Comment: Thank you juanpa, it gives me more understanding that I can't compare these two. Also when I change the while j < oxford[-1] the crash changed as well, now they are both dictionaries, but like you said Python won't let me compare them.

Comment: @Veronica_python, In python, regular dict's cant be indexed or sorted -- There are sorted dicts but I dont think thats what you are after --look up python collections module for addition data structure. Maybe bisect list might help you. At least look at its source code for programming guidance.